# Proper way to close Entity manager

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I have following REST service

```
public class myRestService {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @GET
    @Path("")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getApplications(
            @QueryParam("Id") String Id) throws Exception {
        EntityManager manager = HibernateUtil.getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>(0);

        try {
            transaction.begin();
            Query query = manager.createQuery("select a from Application a where id= :Id");
            query.setParameter("Id", Id);
            applications = query.getResultList();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //manager.close();
        }

        return Response.ok(applications).build();
    }
}
```

The returning statement has infinitive loop as below. I assume this arises because I didn't close the manager.

```
 [{"name":"app1","id":1,"host":"http://www.app1.com","appType":"1","advertiser":{"name":"advertiser1","id":3,"status":"Inactive","applications":[{"name":"app1","id":1,"host":"http://www.app1.com","appType":"1","advertiser":
    {"name":"advertiser1","id":3,"status":"Inactive","applications":......................
```

If I close the manager I get `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.model.Advertiser.applications, could not initialize proxy -` error. I assume this arises because there is no session connected.

Comment: please post the code of your entity class `Application` and `advertiser`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason why you have facing this infinite loop is that you have a cycle in your database configuration.

Something like this (an example):

```
    A db record references B db record
    B db record references A db record
...
```